# Different REST resource content based on user viewing privileges

Tags: web-services, rest, access-rights

I want to provide different answers to the same question for different users, based on the access rights. I read this question:

[Excluding private data in RESTful response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231570/excluding-private-data-in-restful-response)

But I don't agree with the accepted answer, which states that you should provide both `/people.xml` and `/unauthenticated/people.xml`, since my understanding of REST is that a particular resource should live in a particular location, not several depending on how much of its information you're interested in.

The system I'm designing is even more complicated than that one. Let's say that a user has created a number of circles of friends, and assigned different access rights to them. For example, my "acquaintances" circle might have access to my birthday, and my "professional" circle might have access to my employment history, but not the other way around. In order to apply the answer from the question I mentioned, I need to have a way of getting all of the user's circles (which I might want to keep secret for security reasons), and then go through `/circles/a/users/42`, `/circles/b/users/42`, `/circles/c/users/42` and so on, and then merge the results to display the maximum amount of information available. *Obviously there's not necessarily a single circle that gets all the information that any of the other circles get.* I believe this is tricky enough (note that I probably need to do this with several kinds of objects and that future versions might require a different procedure), but what if I want to impose security restrictions on a particular user **despite** the fact that he's also in some of my circles? Can that problem even be solved? Even if I refuse to respond to any of the above-mentioned queries and come up with a new one that could give me an answer, it'd still reveal the fact that this specific user is treated differently due to individual access restrictions.

What am I missing here? Is it even possible for me to develop a RESTful web service?

If the conclusion is that the behavior is not RESTful, would this still constitute as a situation where it'd be morally okay to break the REST contract? If so, what are the negative implications? Do I risk proxy caching issues for example?

Answer (score 33):

According to Fielding's dissertation (it really is a great writing):

> A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

In other words, if you have a resource that is defined as "the requesting user's assigned projects" and representations thereof accessible by a URI of `/projects`, you do not violate any constraints of REST by returning one list of projects (i.e., representation) for user A and another (representation) for user B when they GET that same URI. In this way, the interface is uniform/consistent.

In addition to this, REST only prescribes that an explicit caching instruction be included with the response, whether that is 'cache for this long' or 'do not cache at all':

> Cache constraints require that the data within a response to a request be implicitly or explicitly labeled as cacheable or non-cacheable.

How you choose to manage that is up to you.

**Keeping that in mind,**

You should feel comfortable returning a **representation of a resource** that varies depending on the user requesting a representation of a particular resource, as long as you are not violating the constraints of a uniform interface -- don't use a single resource identifier to return representations of different resources.

If it helps, consider that the server responds with varying representations of a resource as well -- XML or JSON, French or English, etc. The credentials sent with the request are just another factor the server is able to use in determining which representation to to send in response. *That's what the header section is there for.*

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the other solution doesn't seem right.  It makes the URL structure complicated and more difficult to find the resource.  However, if you did REST properly, it shouldn't matter what the URL for the resource is as the server controls it (and is free to relocate it as it sees fit).  If your client is really "REST", it would discover the resources it needed through prior negotiation with the server.  So the path truly would not matter on the client.   I don't like it because its confusing to use - not because of some violation of REST principles.

But that probably doesn't answer your question - 
What you didn't mention is your security setup - presumably you are a passing a session token with the request as part of the request header.  So your back-end processing should have the ability to tie it to particular set of security constraints.  From there, you form the list with whatever business logic you need and return a limited resource based on the user's security tied to the session.

For the algorithm itself, one usually implements a least or most restrictive type algorithm that merges the allowable data into a response (very similar to java realms or Microsoft's user security model).

If the data is structured differently for the restricted/non-restricted case, you could create two different representations of the data and return which ever one the user was authorized to see.  The client should be asking for the accepted mime response types anyway, and it would just provide different answers based on the session security in the request header.   Alternatively, you could provide optional elements with the representations and fill out the appropriate one base on authorization (although this is a little hack-ee in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I understand it, I might want to choose the hack-ee solution if I need to return a non-trivial set of elements based on complex permissions. However, I mentioned caching in my question. To specify: *Is there a risk that a caching proxy (or similar) will distribute the same version of the object to users with different permissions?* Also regarding caching, *how can I inform the client that a resource has changed due to a policy change,* despite an unaltered time-stamp? Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @jeremyth wrote: "it shouldn't matter what the URL for the resource is as the server controls it". For other people ending up here, this concept is know as [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) which is a specific type of REST, it does not apply to all REST concepts.

Comment: @Wilt The phrase "hypermedia as the engine of application state" is used verbatim in Fielding's dissertation. So when you say, "a specific type of REST," what you must really mean is, "the type of REST envisioned by the person who invented the term 'REST'." It's one of the core tenets.

Comment: @mehaase You are right I should have written REST how it is supposed to be but in many REST like solutions this concept is not properly implemented.