# Rest API Return Either Properties based on role or different entity

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm curious when building a proper restful resource, what is the best action to take returning a resource based on a user's role.

For example,
If User 1 calls, GET: api/Users/1
That user should get the base user object (first name, last name, email) along with proprietary information like SSN.
But if User 2 calls, GET: api/Users/1
That user should get the base user object along with maybe their mutual friends they share.

Is this something that is advocated in a restful resource, or would be easier to separate these concerns into something more specific, like api/Users/1/sensitive, and api/Users/1/Friends?

If the former is acceptable, would this be something manageable through inheritance?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use authentication with API calls to decide what information to share and with whom. HTTP Basic Auth!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999295/rest-api-authentication

Comment: @Riya Everyone who can communicate with my APIs are authenticated.  I can then check if the caller who is calling the API is the user being requested.  At that point is it best to return a whole different object if they are or aren't the user, or just hide particular properties?

Comment: Return the same object with less/different properties, if that answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you've made progress since you asked this question.

I will rephrase the statement made in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247218/190476):
It is perfectly under the ambit of REST to return different representations of the same resource based on constraints such as:
Accept header: (e.g. different format like application/json or application/xml)
Authorization: i.e. based on what the caller is "authorized" to see.

The only mandate from REST is that the URI for a resource must be the same. So, consider:
/api/User/1 as the URI for the User resource with ID of 1: Perfectly fine per REST

Whereas:

/api/User/1/private

/api/User/1/public

Isn't RESTful as it provides two URIs for the same resource.